# Determine which active directory object is referred to by GUID in a Directory Synchronization Error Report

Tags: active-directory, exchange, synchronization, hosted-exchange

We have active directory syncronization setup between our on-premises AD server and Microsoft hosted Exchange (business productivity online services).

I've started getting a daily error report, which details an error for a specific AD user, however it references it by GUID.  I can't find any info on how to translate that object guid into something meaningful so I can find and fix the problem.

The error is reported as:

> Error 005: Unable to set the alias for this object in Microsoft Online Services because either the primary SMTP address, the e-mail nickname, or the SAM account name in the local Active Directory contains an invalid character.

in reference to the Object GUID:

> CN={8443cbb4-5199-49f0-9529-ce965430dca6}

How can I translate that object guid into a friendly object name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User objects do have an attribute named 'ObjectGUID'. I believe this is fetchable with a command similar to the following:

dsquery * dc=your,dc=domain -scope sub -filter (ObjectGUID={8443cbb4-5199-49f0-9529-ce965430dca6})

I'm not 100% sure of how to query a GUID, but it should be possible. I can't double-check right now.

Comment: Thanks for that - didn't know about `dsquery`.  I wasn't able to work out how to query by ObjectGUID, but since we've got a relatively small userlist I was able to get a list of users, with the sAMAccountName and ObjectGUID attributes and just lookup the guid from that list in excel.

Comment: @MichaelShimmins We've had dsquery since WinXP, but I didn't know about it until I started futzing with Vista :P.